# XML error: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 3

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
<flipbooks>
<flipbook title="West Indies tour of Bangladesh" flipbookId="5eb06c7b-8389-4a94-9f52-d1f7d1d8bd72">
<thumbnailImage id="138652" src="http://downloads.cricinfo.com//db/PICTURES/CMS/138600/138652.2.jpg"/>
<flipbookDesc/>
<pubDate/>
<flip>
<caption>West Indies tour of Bangladesh</caption>
<image imageId="138616" imageSrc="http://downloads.cricinfo.com//db/PICTURES/CMS/138600/138616.2.jpg"/>
<description>
Mushfiqur Rahim consoles Darren Bravo on missing a double-century
</description>
</flip>
</flipbook>
</flipbooks>
</content>
```

[image]

Any idea what error may be?

As i am newbie for XML I need some guidance...

Thanks...

Comment: This parses fine for me using LibXML2. What parser are you using? Is the error message you're seeing really for this file?

Comment: You need to check this against the schema. That will tell you what it's supposed to look like. Where did you get it and what are you feeding it into.

Comment: @Preet Sangha - well-formedness doesn't depend on the schema.  This looks well-formed.

Comment: For all your comments i posted a image which throws the error..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the processing instruction `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is false, and that the character that we are currently seeing as a single space character, is actually some non UTF-8 character (e.g. `U+00A0`).

If I am right, this is being masked from us by some step along the journey from "sample.xml" to the code sample in your question, and it is being concealed from you by your text editor.

Try removing the processing instruction, or replacing the encoding with `UTF-16` or `ISO-8859-1`.  Also, try loading the xml file in different editors or (if possible) setting the character set in your editor.

When you save the file from your text editor, check any settings that you may have that specify the character set.